# reducing word2vec dimension from Google News Vector Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I loaded google's news vector -300 dataset.  Each word is represented with a 300 point vector.  I want to use this in my neural network for classification.  But 300 for one word seems to be too big.  How can i reduce the vector from 300 to say 100 without compromising on the quality.

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr Use a dimensionality reduction technique like PCA or t-SNE.

This is not a trivial operation that you are attempting. In order to understand why, you must understand what these word vectors are.

Word embeddings are vectors that attempt to encode information about what a word means, how it can be used, and more. What makes them interesting is that they manage to store all of this information as a collection of floating point numbers, which is nice for interacting with models that process words. Rather than pass a word to a model by itself, without any indication of what it means, how to use it, etc, we can pass the model a word vector with the intention of providing extra information about how natural language works.

As I hope I have made clear, word embeddings are pretty neat. Constructing them is an area of active research, though there are a couple of ways to do it that produce interesting results. It's not incredibly important to this question to understand all of the different ways, though I suggest you check them out. Instead, what you really need to know is that each of the values in the 300 dimensional vector associated with a word were "optimized" in some sense to capture a different aspect of the meaning and use of that word. Put another way, each of the 300 values corresponds to some abstract *feature* of the word. Removing any combination of these values at random will yield a vector that may be lacking significant information about the word, and may no longer serve as a good representation of that word.

So, picking the top 100 values of the vector is no good. We need a more principled way to reduce the dimensionality. What you really want is to sample a subset of these values such that as much information as possible about the word is retained in the resulting vector. This is where a dimensionality reduction technique like Principle Component Analysis (PCA) or t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embeddings (t-SNE) come into play. I won't describe in detail how these methods work, but essentially they aim to capture the essence of a collection of information while reducing the size of the vector describing said information. As an example, PCA does this by constructing a new vector from the old one, where the entries in the new vector correspond to combinations of the main "components" of the old vector, i.e those components which account for most of the variety in the old data.

To summarize, you should run a dimensionality reduction algorithm like PCA or t-SNE on your word vectors. There are a number of python libraries that implement both (e.g scipy has a PCA algorithm). Be warned, however, that the dimensionality of these word vectors is already relatively low. To see how this is true, consider the task of naively representing a word via its one-hot encoding (a one at one spot and zeros everywhere else). If your vocabulary size is as big as the google word2vec model, then each word is suddenly associated with a vector containing hundreds of thousands of entries! As you can see, the dimensionality has already been reduced significantly to 300, and any reduction that makes the vectors significantly smaller is likely to lose a good deal of information.

Answer (score -4):

@narasimman I suggest that you simply keep the top 100 numbers in the output vector of the word2vec model. The output is of type numpy.ndarray so you can do something like:

```
>>> word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('modelConfig/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
>>> type(word_vectors["hello"])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> word_vectors["hello"][:10]
array([-0.05419922,  0.01708984, -0.00527954,  0.33203125, -0.25      ,
       -0.01397705, -0.15039062, -0.265625  ,  0.01647949,  0.3828125 ], dtype=float32)
>>> word_vectors["hello"][:2]
array([-0.05419922,  0.01708984], dtype=float32)
```

I don't think that this will screw up the result if you do it to all the words (not sure though!)